# Angular2 router: matching any url, including subdirectories

Tags: angular, routes, seo

I'm updating an old website with Angular2, and one of the prerequisites is that all URLs must still match.

It's the very beginning of the development and I'm working on the router.

So far, I have to create a homePage, a productPage and an errorPage.

The "old" links for a product page are like this :
`/category/subcategory/some/eventual/other/things/productName-id.html`

I've copied [Matan Shukry's Complex Url Matcher](https://gist.github.com/matanshukry/22fae5dba9c307baf0f364a9c9f7c115), and here's my current code :

```
import { ComplexUrlMatcher } from '../../functions/complex.url.matcher';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path:      '',
        component: HomepageComponent,
    },
    {
        matcher:   ComplexUrlMatcher('product', /.*/), // very permissive regex here, in order to test
        component: ProductComponent,
    },
    {
        path:      '**',
        component: Error404Component,
    },
];
```

My current problem is that I can match anything, provided my url does not have any slash.

- `/abcdefg.html` works (Loads the ProductComponent)
- `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g.html` doesn't (Loads the Error404Component)
- `/a/bcdefg.html` doesn't neither

How can I make these urls match with their full paths (including all the slashes ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way, helped by [anein's function](https://gist.github.com/anein/fba647b4206695d109c30e1fc0d2e8ee) (Thanks, dude !).

Matan Shukry's method was unnecessary complex for my needs.

Here's the gist I made : https://gist.github.com/MarcBrillault/87f8df9610cfa3ed112afc3f8da474e8

Edit: gist updated.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to go with `parameters` in angular you can define parameters to the route

```
{ path: 'hero/:a/:b/:c/:d/:e/:f/:g', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'hero/:a/:b/:c/:d/:e/:f', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'hero/:a/:b/:c/:d/:e', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'hero/:a/:b/:c/:d', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'hero/:a/:b/:c', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'hero/:a/:b', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'hero/:a', component: HeroDetailComponent },
{ path: 'hero', component: HeroDetailComponent },
```

Then subscribe to paramMap

```
HeroDetailComponent 

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
) { }

this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
});
```

you will get all the parameters in the subscription and do you operations

here `id` is a parameter. same way you can pass multiple parameters to your route
to create your route structure

https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional go this link for more details

Comment: The different directories are dynamic (ie evolving with the database), and there are a lot of them. Also, I also want to match other eventual routes having directories as well.